# How to refresh or update listview using BaseAdapter?

Tags: android

I have been trying to refresh the `listview` whenever I delete the row in it. I have used `BaseAdapter` for `listview`. I am not getting how to refresh it. I used SQLite and while refreshing I am deleting the row in Database as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DataBase md ;
    ImageButton ib;
    ListView notelist;
    int i;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> not = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> Revtitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Revnot = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Revdate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Revtime = new ArrayList<String>();


    DataAdapter adapter;

    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        md = new DataBase(this);

        SQLiteDatabase sd = md.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = sd.query(md.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            titles.add(c.getString(0));
            not.add(c.getString(1));
            date.add(c.getString(2));
            time.add(c.getString(3));

        }

        for (int i = titles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            Revtitles.add(titles.get(i));
            Revnot.add(not.get(i));
            Revdate.add(date.get(i));
            Revtime.add(time.get(i));

        }

        notelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        adapter = new DataAdapter(this);
        notelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        // notelist.setStackFromBottom(true);
        notelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show.class);

                i.putExtra("TITLE", Revtitles.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("NOTE", Revnot.get(arg2));

                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

        notelist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    final int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String st = Revtitles.get(pos);
                String st1 = Revnot.get(pos);

                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                ad.setMessage("Are sure you want to delete?");
                ad.setCancelable(false);
                ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //sd.delete(md.TABLE_NAME, md.COL_ROLLNO+"=?", new String[]{st});

                    //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(i);

                ///////PROBLEM LINES///////



                        SQLiteDatabase sd = md.getWritableDatabase();

                        sd.delete(md.TABLE_NAME,md.COL_TITLE+"=?", new String[]{st});

                        Revtitles.remove(pos);
                        Revnot.remove(pos);
                        Revdate.remove(pos);
                        Revtime.remove(pos);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                        notelist.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }



                });
                ad.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog adl = ad.create();
                adl.show();
                return true;
            }

        });

        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context con;
        LayoutInflater lat = getLayoutInflater();

        public DataAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.con = mainActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return titles.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convo, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            convo = lat.inflate(R.layout.mainlist, null);

            TextView tit = (TextView)convo.findViewById(R.id.inflatetitle);
            TextView datea = (TextView)convo.findViewById(R.id.inflatedate);
            String rtitle;

            int len = Revtitles.get(position).length();
            if (len <= 20){
             rtitle = Revtitles.get(position);
            }
            else {
                rtitle = Revtitles.get(position).substring(0, 20) + "...";
            }
            tit.setText(rtitle);
            datea.setText(Revdate.get(position) + "\n" + Revtime.get(position));

            view = convo;
            return convo;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should _not_ call `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();`, please see relevant doc: "Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data is no longer valid or available. Once invoked this adapter is no longer valid and should not report further data set changes." (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated())

Answer (score 0):

you are using `getView()` to adapt data from `SQLite` to your `listView`, after you delete an item in the `listView` you should update your `listview` to change the data in it.

you bind you data using `notelist.setAdapter(adapter);`  to you `listview` .

so to refresh your `listView` you have to notify the `adapter` that something has happened and he should refresh by using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

you can do this inside your `listview class` or in the `adapter class`

use this method inside the adapter class :

```
public void updateAdapter(your_list arrylst ) {
    this.arrylst= arrylst;

    //and call notifyDataSetChanged
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

btw your using a bad `getVeiw()`  method , as in Google I/O 2013 said.

check [this video for more info](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

hope that helped